# .NET MVC2 Multiple Partial Views on Master, also individually loadable via AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I'm creating a single-page site using MVC2 and thus a few different pages will be visible like so in HTML divs:

```
==========
|Section1|
|        |
==========
==========
|Section2|
|        |
==========
==========
|Section3|
|        |
==========
```

Let's call this landing page /Home/Index - in the Home/Index view there's just a few RenderAction calls to render Section1/Index, Section2/Index and Section3/Index - each of the sections is a controller.

At various points, a different part of Section1, Section2 or Section3 will be loaded into their respective divs by making an Ajax Request to /Section1/Part1 or /Section2/Part3 etc, etc.

I know already that the best way to have the page loaded the first time would be to have partial views for each of these sections, and putting those in.

But say I wanted to go to /Section2/Part3 *without* using an AJAX request, what would be the best way to ensure that I get Section1, Section2 and Section3 on the page showing but, instead of the default Partial View for Section2, we show Part3.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

One I had was: somehow returning from the Section actions a /Home/Index view with the Model data required to know to render the specified part - but I don't want to redirect as the URL needs to stay the same.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks :)

P.S. Not using .NET Ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue may be solved by using `Request.IsAjax` in your action methods.  If you have an AJAX request, return the partial view.  If not, return a regular view that includes the partial.

```
public ActionResult Part1() {
    /* Other code here */

    if(!Request.IsAjax)
        return View("Part1Full");

    return View();
}
```

In your `Part1Full` view, just call `RenderPartial("Part1")`.  I'm assuming it will also work if you call `RenderAction("Part1")` but if not look into the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.  You can find more information on that [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, this is exactly how I'll do it :)